# Polygon with n peaks, Plane sweep algorithm will add Θ(n) diagonals when converting to monotones

Tags: notation, big-o

The algorithm runs in Ο(nlogn).

We are asked to find a polygon with n edges for which, when we use the plane sweep algorithm for converting a polygon to monotones, the algorithm will add **Θ(n)** diagonals.

So then that means that we have **k1*g(n) <= f(n) <= k2*g(n)**, 
what i understand is that in this case f(n) is how many diagonals i will have, and if that is right then what would g(n) be? would it be **n**? or **nlogn**? or neither? n seems pretty large for diagonals and nlogn is not much better.

Also since we are looking for a number and not a function, then could we say **diagonals = k1*g(n)**?

I understand (or at least i think so) how the notations work but i am really confused as to how i would go about to solving this problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for you time.